# show loading or progress bar in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have windows application in which i need to save data into database and after saving data load crystal report to show report,all this happens on click of save button.

I have button named **`btn_Submit`** on click of this data is saved and display report, while saving it takes time so i want to show progress bar for mean time so that user get known that data is in process.how i can do with this windows application.

I gone through this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo  but don't get it exactly I want.

I am aware of background worker but never used it.

I have used background worker and progress bar as given in above link but progress bar does not stop at all once it started.

Can any one help me?can u give any example or link that demonstrate scenario?.

This code i added on Dowork();

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   PrintData arg = (PrintData)e.Argument;
   SalesMaster sm = arg.SalesData;
   BrokerMaster bm = arg.Broker;
   CustomerMaster ctm = arg.Customer;
   CompanyMaster cm = arg.Company;
   ArrayList hb = arg.Arrardata;
   int totunit = arg.totunit;
   decimal globalamt = arg.golbamt;
   SalesReport sreport = new SalesReport(sm, ctm, cm, bm, hb, totunit, glb_totalamt);


   sreport .MdiParent = arg.parentf;


   sreport .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
   sreport .Show();
}
```

i get error on this line   **sreport .MdiParent = arg.parentf;**

This error:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'frmParent' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

what should be done here?

Comment: Are you saving report as one big save operation (progress bar just show that something happen in background), or you have several saving steps which should be reflected by progress bar (progress bar shows real percentage of operation completion)?

Comment: no it's not required to show percentage that how much done,just want to show loading or please wait type of markings while background work is done

Answer (score 3):

Suscribe to `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events and

```
void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn_Submit.Enabled = false; // disable button while saving report        
    lbl_Status.Text = "Please wait..";        
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 
}

void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // save report here
}

void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    btn_Submit.Enabled = true; // enable button
    lbl_Status.Text = "Report saved";
}
```

Instead of using label, you can show `PictureBox` with spinner wait image. I don't like to see progress bar, which does not show percentage of task - I expect that when progress bar will be filled, task will be completed. If you really want to use progress bar, then, I'd go with timer component (set timer's interval to desired refresh rate):

```
void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn_Submit.Enabled = false; // disable button while saving report       
    timer.Start();
    progressBar.Visible = true;
    //  backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new object[] { "Foo", 42 });  
    //  backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new CustomType("Foo", 42));   
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new { Foo = "Foo", Bar = 42 }););      
}

void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // object[] args = (object[])e.Argument;
    // CustomType arg = (CustomType)e.Argument;
    dynamic arg = (dynamic)e.Argument;
    string foo = arg.Foo;
    int bar = arg.Bar;
    // save report here
}

void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    btn_Submit.Enabled = true; // enable button
    timer.Stop();
    progressBar.Visible = false;   
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar.Value == progressBar.Maximum)
    {
        progressBar.Value = progressBar.Minimum;
        return;
    }

    progressBar.PerformStep();
}
```

Comment: hi,in backgroundWorker_DoWork() how i can pass multiple parameters
And also **backgroundWorker** from where u get this should i drag and drop from toolbox?

Comment: @user1850707 yes, both backgroundWorker and timer are available from toolbox, see components group. You can pass complex object or array to `RunWorkerAsync`.

Comment: thanks,how can i pass multiple parameteres to backgroundWorker_DoWork() or backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()?????

Comment: @sharad `e.Argument` of `DoWork` handler will contain that object. I have updated last sample with multiple parameters passing.

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky,i got the error while running application.
i have added in my code have look on it.what should be done here.

Comment: @user1850707 cross-thread UI operations are not allowed in .net. You can't set `MdiParent` because it was created on other thread. Also whole approach is not good - you should have `SalesReport` form on your main thread, and delegate only report saving to backgroundworker.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset the ProgressBar's Value property to 0, like in the code below:

```
Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

Implemented event handler:

```
void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop or hide the progressbar use background worker's completed event.